# Threading not working properly when function is in another module

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm currently using a daemon thread in Python to constantly detect parts of the screen in the background while other more important functions are running. `testImToStr` is in the same file as the rest of the code I am using.

```
    def testImToStr():
        while True:
           pospro.imagetoString();

    doImageToString = threading.Thread(target=testImToStr, args=(), daemon=True)
    doImageToString.start()
    while True:
        #other stuff i was too lazy to copy over
```

This version is working as it does both the image processing and the other stuff in the while loop.
However, then the target thread is in another module:

```
    doImageToString = threading.Thread(target=pospro.loopedImToStr, args=(), daemon=True)
    doImageToString.start()
    while True:
        #other stuff i was too lazy to copy over
```

Other module:

```
    def loopedImToStr():
        while True:
            imagetoString()

    def imagetoString():
        #stuff here
```

It only loops the target thread and does not run the while loop in the file that originally made the thread. How is it that both loops are run when the thread is in the same file as the loop but only the thread is run when it they are in different files?

Comment: the most common mistake - `target` has to be function's name without `()`  (so called `callback`)- `target=pospro.loopedImToStr` - and later `Thread` will use `()` to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all your problem makes the most common mistake - `target` has to be function's name without `()`  - so called `callback`

```
Thread(target=pospro.loopedImToStr, daemon=True)
```

and later `Thread.start()` will use `()` to run it.

In your code you run `testImToStr()` at once like

```
result = testImToStr()

doImageToString = threading.Thread(target=result, ...)
```

so `testImToStr()` blocks all code and it can't run other loop.